# Why poll for STDIN returns 0 even though select succeeded?

Tags: windows-10, stdin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to run a command line example from the [OpenThread](https://github.com/openthread/openthread) GitHub project on WSL and have found that [the code](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/master/examples/platforms/posix/uart.c) that calls `poll` on STDIN doesn't seem to be working.

The code waits on a number of handles with a `select` call. That returns correctly when a key is pressed, but when it immediately calls `poll`, the function just returns 0. If I comment out the `poll` call and directly call `read`, that seems to return the correct result.

Is this a bug with WSL or does the code need to be adapted somehow to work in this environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the solution was to not use `POLLRDNORM`, but instead use `POLLIN` for the `poll` call. Apparently, `POLLRDNORM` is unsupported right now.